# how to pass array of image and json object to api in android using retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

[post man screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kQMi.png) this is my post man screen short of postman i am facing issue while uploading multiple image in array using @part or @post in retrofit

```
@Multipart
@POST("customers/posts")    
fun upload_post(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String?,
                @Part("title") title: RequestBody,
                @Part("description") description: RequestBody,
                @Part surveyImagesParts: Array<MultipartBody.Part?>,
                @Part("tags") tags: JSONObject,
                @Part("mentions") mentions: JSONObject
): Call<post_main_sample>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send multiple arrays,image then use raw method in api.This is best for it but here is the solution:

interface method

```
@Multipart
@POST("customers/posts") 
fun upload_post(
@Part images: List<MultipartBody.Part>
): Single<String>
```

activity code

```
fun readyFilePart(name: String, file: File): MultipartBody.Part {
val requestBodyFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file)
return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.name, requestBodyFile)
}

val listOfImages = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()
for (i in 0 until images.size) {
listOfImages.add(readyFilePart("image[$i]", images[i]))
}
```

call like this:

```
upload_post(listOfImages)
```

Comment: im facing "D/OkHttp: <-- 422 Unprocessable Entity" this type of error while uploading image in api

Comment: this error occur when you upload wrong type,missing paramter etc make sure that the all parameter same and its type also same

Comment: can you please suggest me how to pass this type of data in api ->{"user_ids" : ["12", "13"]}

Comment: convert api response into raw like json it's easily to send these data